# Wget fails to download a pdf from a direct link

Tags: python, http, pdf, download, wget

I am trying to use **wget** to download a **pdf** file.
I have a [direct link](https://prospektbestellung.nordseetourismus.de/mediafiles/Sonstiges/Ortsprospekte/amrum2021.pdf) to the pdf document and input the following into command line:

```
wget -A pdf -nc -np -nd --content-disposition --wait=1 --tries=5 "https://prospektbestellung.nordseetourismus.de/mediafiles/Sonstiges/Ortsprospekte/amrum2021.pdf"
```

This uses a lot of unnecessary options, but they should not mess with the outcome, which is:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Unknown error) in headers.
```

Is there any way to fix this directly using wget or are there any other solutions, preferably in Python, which I could consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*any other solutions, preferably in Python, which I could consider?*

You might use [`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) from built-in module `urllib.request` as follows

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://prospektbestellung.nordseetourismus.de/mediafiles/Sonstiges/Ortsprospekte/amrum2021.pdf","amrum2021.pdf")
```

this code does download file and save it under name `amrum2021.pdf` in current working directory. Unlike `requests` `urllib.request` is built-in module so no additional installation beyond python itself is required.

Answer (score 1):

When using WGET its sending it's own headers and the only one that will be different from the browser is the user-agent.

You can pick the user-agent from your browser or just get a random one online and set it as a header during the request.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

Your oneliner works for me. I've successfully download pdf.

```
wget -A pdf -nc -np -nd --content-disposition --wait=1 --tries=5 "https://prospektbestellung.nordseetourismus.de/mediafiles/Sonstiges/Ortsprospekte/amrum2021.pdf"
```

I believe there is network or firewall issue.

Answer (score 1):

A python based solution below

```
import requests

url = 'https://prospektbestellung.nordseetourismus.de/mediafiles/Sonstiges/Ortsprospekte/amrum2021.pdf'
r = requests.get(url)
with open('my_file.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```